# Attempt to prove that every orientable connected manifold has exactly two orientations (Munkres)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am looking at Munkres' book Analysis on Manifolds and come across the following exercise:

> Show that if M is a connected orientable $k$-manifold in $\mathbb R^n$, then M has precisely two orientations

Here is my attempt (following the hint from the book):

> Choose an orientation of $M$; it consists of a collection of coordinate patches $\{\alpha_i\}$. Let $\{\beta_j\}$ be an arbitrary (fixed) orientation of $M$. Given $\mathbf x \in M$, choose coordinate patches $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ about $\mathbf x$ and define $\lambda(\mathbf x)=1$ if they overlap positively at $\mathbf x$, and $\lambda(\mathbf x)=-1$ if they overlap negatively at $\mathbf x$.
>
> First we note that $\lambda$ is well defined. Choose any two pairs of patches, say $\alpha_1,\beta_1$ and $\alpha_2,\beta_2$, with
> $$
> \alpha_1(t_1)=\beta_1(s_1)=\mathbf x=\alpha_2(t_2)=\beta_2(s_2).
> $$
> Suppose $\alpha_1,\beta_1$ overlap positively at $\mathbf x$, then
> $$
> \alpha_2^{-1}\circ\beta_2=\left(\alpha_2^{-1}\circ\alpha_1\right)\circ\left(\alpha_1^{-1}\circ\beta_1\right)\circ\left(\beta_1^{-1}\circ\beta_2\right).
> $$
> at some neighrborhood around $\mathbf x$. It follows that $\alpha_2,\beta_2$ overlap positively iff $\alpha_1,\beta_1$ do.
>
> Now, suppose $\alpha:U\to V$ and $\beta:O\to P$ overlap positively at $\mathbf x$, say with $\alpha(t_0)=\beta(s_0)=\mathbf x$. Since $V\cap P$ is an open subset of $M$ containing $\mathbf x$, take a connected open neighborhood $W$ of $s_0$ so that $\beta(W)\subset V\cap P$. Since $\beta^{-1}$ is continuous, $\beta(W)$ is an open neighborhood of $\mathbf x$. Consider the function $f:W\to\mathbb R$ defined by $f(s)=\det(D(\alpha^{-1}\beta)(s))$, then $f(s_0)>0$ by assumption. Moreover, $f\ne0$ on $W$ since transition functions have nonsingular derivative. Since $W$ is connected, $f$ does not change sign on $W$, so $\alpha$ and $\beta$ overlap positively on $W$. An entirely similar argument holds for the case where $\alpha$, $\beta$ overlap negatively at $\mathbf x$. Hence, $\lambda$ is continuous.
>
> Thus, since $M$ is connected, $\lambda$ is either identically $1$ or identically $-1$. If $\lambda$ is identically $1$, then every patch in $\{\beta_j\}$ overlaps positively with patches in $\{\alpha_i\}$, whence $\{\beta_j\}\subset\{\alpha_i\}\subset\{\beta_j\}$ by the definition of orientation. The other case is similar. Hence, $\{\beta_j\}$ is either the same as $\{\alpha_i\}$ or the opposite orientation to $\{\alpha_i\}$.

Can anybody tell me if my proof is correct? I have seen some similar questions on stackexchange, but they seem to assume different backgrounds and do not apply to the book I'm reading now.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit: If two patches $\alpha,\beta$ "overlap positively," the book means the transition function $\alpha^{-1}\circ\beta$ is orientation-preserving, i.e. its derivative has positive determinant everywhere on the domain ($\det(D(\alpha^{-1}\circ\beta)(x))>0$).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I think local constant is what I'm trying to show. If one only knows that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ overlap positively **at the point $\mathbf x$**, I don't think it is obvious that they overlap positively on a neighborhood of $\mathbf x$. Could you provide more details?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same choice of alpha and beta to define lambda for all points at a connected neighborhood of $\mathbf x$. But how do you know that $\lambda$ stays constant over that neighborhood? You only know that the two patches overlap positively at the point $\mathbf x$. ️

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I just edited the question to add this info. Could you take a look? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you overlap positively at $x$, you overlap positively in some neighbourhood of $x$, specifically in the neighbourhood where $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ intersect right? They can't intersect just at $x$ since open sets intersect in an open set. The same charts work for points in this intersection, so this shows it's locally constant. Now you have a locally constant function on a connected manifold...

Comment: @OsamaGhani Your claim "If you overlap positively at $x$, you overlap positively in some neighbourhood of $x$" is what I am trying to prove in the third paragraph. Is there an obvious way to see this?
More importantly, I think $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ need not overlap positively at everywhere they intersect. If the intersection is not connected, the determinant might change sign, am I correct? That is why I invoked the connectedness argument in the third paragraph.

Comment: I think you're getting confused. Pick your $x$ and pick $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ such that $x \in \alpha_i, \beta_i$. Lots of choices made here but you've already shown that choice of the patch doesn't matter. If $x$ is in this intersection, then it lies in the intersection of two open sets so it is open yet again. You are right that this need not be connected. No worries - take the connected component of the intersection that $x$ lies in, then on this piece, the determinant (by definition/construction) does not change sign since the same patches work for any other point in that intersection.

Comment: Thus, for any $x$, there is an open set about $x$ where all patches $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$ that include $x$ either intersect positively or negatively. So $\lambda$ is a locally constant function.

Comment: @OsamaGhani Right, that's why I take the *connected* neighborhood $W$. One thing though: the determinant function is defined on a subset of the domain of $\beta$, so I'm worried that you can't simply take the connected component of $x$, which is on the manifold. The determinant function $\det(\alpha^{-1}\circ\beta)$ is simply not defined there. Is this correct?

Comment: I think I'm not understanding your issue. You are taking the connected component of $x$ in the intersection, the whole determinant business works well there. Also your definition of positive overlap says that the determinant is positive on a domain, not at the point, so I'm not sure this discussion is relevant.

Comment: The domain of the transition map $\alpha^{-1}\circ\beta$ is a subset of the domain of $\beta$, and the determinant of $\alpha^{-1}\circ\beta$ is defined there. That's what I meant.